# CCBlade does not work on the cocos2d-x 3.8 version

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.x

-My platform       : Mac

-cocos2d-x Version : 3.8.1

-Tool              :Xcode

-TestDevice        : ios Simulator

i used this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/ChipmunkCommunityCN/RockChipmunk2D/tree/master/Classes/FruitCutNinja)

i implemented to the blade effect, as in "Fruit Ninja App".

it is no problem on the cocos2d-x3.0 version.

but...

CCBlade does not work on the cocos2d-x 3.8 version.

help me~

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void Blade::onDraw(const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    getGLProgram()->use();
    getGLProgram()->setUniformsForBuiltins(transform);

    GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_TEX_COORD|GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION);

    GL::blendFunc(_blendFunc.src,_blendFunc.dst);

    GL::bindTexture2D( _texture->getName() );

    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _coordinates);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)(2 * _path.size() - 2));
    CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWN_BATCHES_AND_VERTICES(1, (2 * _path.size() - 2));
}
void Blade::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform,uint32_t flags)
{
    if ((_reset && _path.size() > 0) || (_autoDim && _willPop))
    {
        pop(1);
        if (_path.size() < 3)
        {
            clear();
        }
    }

    if (_path.size() < 3)
    {
        return;
    }

    _willPop = true;

     CCASSERT(_texture, "NO TEXTURE SET");
    _custumCamand.init(_globalZOrder,transform,flags);
    _custumCamand.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(Blade::onDraw,this,transform,flags);
    renderer->addCommand(&_custumCamand);
}
```